# Why does python multiprocessing Pool.map() RAM consumption increase over time?

Tags: python, memory, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing, ram

**Simplified scenario**

**tl;dr:** See code snippet below. Here I just explain what it's supposed to do and why.

I have an object `example_class_instance` of a class `ExampleClassWithTonOfData` that holds a ton of random data (in the original problem the data is read from file during run time).

`example_class_instance` has a method `change_inplace()` that takes an object of another class `ObjectThatNeedsToBeModified` and modifies it inplace using its stored data.

I have a function `do_work` that takes an object of `ObjectThatNeedsToBeModified`, passes it to `example_class_instance.change_inplace()` and returns the modified object.

I want to do this modification for a ton of objects and I want to do it using multiprocessing.
I use the `multiprocessing.Pool`'s `map()` function for this purpose.

As far as I know, `map()` will not begin yielding until all tasks have been submitted, i.e. until all objects of `ObjectThatNeedsToBeModified` have been assigned to a process. To avoid memory issues, I therefore only pass batches of objects to the executor map instead of an iterator over all objects.
To this end, I create one `object_iterator` function that iterates over all objects I want to modify and one `batch_iterator` function that uses the `object_iterator` function and yields batches of objects.

I then iterate over the created batches and pass each batch to the `map()` function with the `do_work()` function.

Here is the code for this minimal example:

```python
import psutil
import random
import multiprocessing

random.seed(42)

BATCH_SIZE = 1000
N_PROCESSES = 8
STORED_DATA_SIZE = 100000000
N_OBJECTS = 10000000
N_OBJECTS_VAL_RANGE = 100000


class ObjectThatNeedsToBeModified:
    def __init__(self):
        self.c = None


class ExampleClassWithTonOfData:
    # Class that holds an object with a huge memory footprint
    def __init__(self):
        self.lot_of_data = [random.randint(0, 100000) for _ in range(STORED_DATA_SIZE)]

    def change_inplace(self, object):
        object.c = self.lot_of_data[random.randint(0, STORED_DATA_SIZE-1)]


def do_work(args_tuple):
    example_class_instance.change_inplace(args_tuple)
    return args_tuple


def object_iterator():
    for _ in range(N_OBJECTS):
        yield ObjectThatNeedsToBeModified()


def batch_iterator(iterator):
    tuples = []
    for res_tuple in iterator:
        tuples.append(res_tuple)
        if len(tuples) >= BATCH_SIZE:
            yield tuples
            tuples = []

    if len(tuples) > 0:
        yield tuples


def main():
    print()
    info = p.memory_full_info()
    print(f"PSS: {getattr(info, 'pss'):> 10}, USS: {getattr(info, 'uss'):> 10}, RSS: {getattr(info, 'rss'):> 10}")

    print("Start working with %d processes." % N_PROCESSES)
    iterator = object_iterator()
    with multiprocessing.Pool(processes=N_PROCESSES) as executor:
        i = 0
        for batch in batch_iterator(iterator):
            for _ in executor.map(do_work, batch):
                if (i + 1) % (N_OBJECTS // 30) == 0:
                    info = p.memory_full_info()
                    print(f"PSS: {getattr(info, 'pss'):> 10}, USS: {getattr(info, 'uss'):> 10}, RSS: {getattr(info, 'rss'):> 10}")
                i += 1


if __name__ == "__main__":
    p = psutil.Process()
    print("Loading data")
    example_class_instance = ExampleClassWithTonOfData()

    main()
```

**Problem**

The memory consumption increases as long as the program is running.
The output using psutil looks something like this:

```python
PSS:  4051436544, USS:  4050128896, RSS:  4056670208
Start working with 8 processes.
PSS:  474577920, USS:    4972544, RSS:  4057817088
PSS:  495186944, USS:    5177344, RSS:  4057817088
PSS:  516726784, USS:    5181440, RSS:  4057817088
PSS:  539525120, USS:    5181440, RSS:  4057817088
PSS:  563405824, USS:    5218304, RSS:  4057817088
PSS:  588656640, USS:    5283840, RSS:  4057817088
PSS:  615304192, USS:    5423104, RSS:  4057817088
PSS:  643209216, USS:    5787648, RSS:  4057817088
PSS:  672796672, USS:    6475776, RSS:  4057817088
PSS:  703847424, USS:    7737344, RSS:  4057817088
PSS:  736442368, USS:    9609216, RSS:  4057817088
PSS:  770696192, USS:   12574720, RSS:  4057817088
PSS:  806727680, USS:   16683008, RSS:  4057817088
...
```

Interestingly, `htop` does not show this memory increase when looking at the processes, but the overall RAM consumption that is displayed increases.

**What I've tried**

Deleting `batch` after it was used has no effect.

The problem seems to have to do with the data loaded in `ExampleClassWithTonOfData`:
If in `example_class_instance.change_inplace()` instead of using the stored data to modify the object, the object is assigned a constant value, the problem goes away.

As far as I know the data of the parent process is copied only if the child processes modify the data. Here however, the data of `ExampleClassWithTonOfData` is only modified once in its `__init__` method.

Can someone explain why the memory consumption is increasing so drastically over time and how to avoid it? Any help is appreciated.

*The provided code snippet is a full code example and should produce the described results when copied & pasted.*

Comment: You should probably just use `map(..., chunksize=...)` instead of rolling `batch_iterator` yourself. Also see `.imap_unordered()` if the order of iteration doesn't matter.

Comment: Also remember that the changes to `example_class_instance`'s properties are _not_ propagated across process boundaries, so your program in effect does nothing.

Comment: I tried setting `chunksize` as well as using `imap()` (the order does matter so i can't use `imap_unordered()`), both of which did not help. And note that I don't change `example_class_instance`'s properties but those of the instances of `ObjectThatNeedsToBeModified` which I pass to `do_work` and thus to `change_inplace()`.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I got confused by the nomenclature – it sounds like `change_inplace` changes the object itself in-place.

Comment: By the way, your example only works if `multiprocessing`'s start method is `"fork"` (which it is on Linux, but not on other platforms by default), since otherwise `example_class_instance` isn't implicitly COW'd into the subprocesses.

Comment: I'm unable to repro this (using `.imap()` and no chunksize) on my macOS machine - `rss` remains stable and `uss` actually decreases as soon as the subprocesses are spawned, since those pages are no longer unique. (Using `chunksize` doesn't change that situation, but makes the program _a lot_ faster due to less serialization overhead.)

Comment: Hmm interesting (and thanks for looking into this :) ), I'm on Linux. But you can see in my output snippet, too, that the RSS stays more or less the same and USS first decreases as you said once the subprocesses are spawned for the reason you mention, but then RSS increases again over time, as does PSS. You can't observe this increase over time?

Comment: I tried my modified code in a Docker container and can't observe a drastic increase in `rss` (`uss` and `pss` do fluctuate, but not a lot). Give https://gist.github.com/akx/3b651934ebbb8eae79293641c64ac343 a shot?

Comment: I do observe a severe increase in both USS and PSS (but not not RSS). From the step after the processes are spawned with: 0 (rss=420069376, ..., uss=2859008, pss=48967680) to the last step with: 9900000 (rss=421695488, ..., uss=332439552, pss=342002688, swap=0).

Comment: You're right, I was eyeballing the results wrong. However, interestingly the increase is not linear - if you look at e.g. `psutil.virtual_memory().percent`, the overall memory use will plateau after a while. With `maxtasksperchild`, it's fairly stable (with local fluctuation of course). Since each _access_ to a Python object will also invalidate the COW'd page the object's refcount is in, that might explain it - over time all of the integers in `lot_of_data` will have been accessed, so all of the child processes have their own copies of the data...

Comment: Yep, that would actually be it – without `maxtasksperchild`, swapping the list of integers for `self.lot_of_data = array.array('L', ...)` (which doesn't have reference counting for each member), memory use remains static.

Answer (score 2):

Setting the `maxtasksperchild` parameter in `Pool()` solves the issue.

From Python documentation:

> *maxtasksperchild* is the number of tasks a worker process can complete
> before it will exit and be replaced with a fresh worker process, to
> enable unused resources to be freed. The default maxtasksperchild is
> None, which means worker processes will live as long as the pool.

The fact that settings `maxtasksperchild` solves the issue seems to indicate that memory is leaking (See https://stackoverflow.com/a/54975030/7097579).

But I still don't understand where or why this is happening.

Comment: Python memory management is complicated... This is exactly the solution I would recommend anyway. If you're interested in further reading, iirc one of the big tech companies that runs their stack on python (twitter maybe?) went to a fairly significant effort to fork cPython such that large chunks of loaded memory are fairly static so that they can fork processes and actually leverage copy-on-write memory allocation (normal garbage collection touches almost everything, so no data is particularly static). Even with that, they periodically re-start worker processes to free resources.

Comment: some additional reading [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29838782/3220135) as well...